# @JsonManaged reference detail list wrong size

Tags: json, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've been taking my first steps with SpringData, and so far feeling very comfortable with It, However I'm facing this issue which I seem  I don't entirely understand how it should work yet.

Let's say I have two entities mapped with the following anotations:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Check> checks;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(updatable = false)
@JsonView({EntityView.Full.class})
@JsonBackReference
private Deposit deposit;
```

Having only one record on the master Entity and other on the detail Table,
How come I always get a Cheque details list with a length different than one?

I Hope I made myself clear and and I want to give Thanks in advance to all of you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You write about two entities but post only two attributes!? What is in the additional elements of the list? How do you set up/create the instances? Is length always a fixed number different than one? Which one? Or does it change on every invocation?

Comment: Hi Jens! I kept looking for a possible cause, when I ran the same tests on my technical leader's machine, we found that it was behaving the way it Is supposed to.

Meaning that the elements on the details list had no strange duplicates.

We concluded that one of the possible causes was that I executed some DML directly over the database (nothing unusual) apparently it affected somehow the integrity of the data. So, in the end we decided to delete and create the whole test database again and now it's working like a charm :)

The details list always has a different size BTW :)
Thank you